# how to invoke a dynamically loaded javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, closures

I was implementing a on-demand script controller based on jquery's getscript, it looks like this:

```
function controller = function(){

   var script = function(){
      var scripts = {};
      return {
        load: function(jsurl){
          $.getScript(jsurl, null);
        },
        run: function(js){
          window[js].apply(this,null);
        }
      }
   };

  return {
    script: script()
  };

}

var ctlr = controller();
```

then here is a remote script with a function to be loaded - remote.js

```
function remotefunc(){
  alert( 'remotefunc invoked' );
}
```

and here is how the whole thing supposed to work, in the main script:

```
ctlr.script.load( 'remote.js' ); // remote script successfully loaded
ctlr.script.run( 'remotefunc' ); // got an error, window['remotefunc'] undefined
```

but as you can see, 'remotefunc' is defined in the global 'window' scope, so the window object is supposed to be able to 'see' it.

I thought the problem was probably the closure stuff in the 'controller' definition, so I did a direct $.getScirpt without using the 'controller':

```
$.getScript( 'http://path/to/remote.js', function(){
  window['remotefunc'].apply( this, null );  // this worked
} );
```

strange. So it is about the 'controller' implementation(I kind need it)! Anybody can help me out with this? How to fix the 'controller' implementation so the

```
 window[js].apply(this,null);
```

can actually work?

Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using something like `getSript`, it's important to remember that it is fetching **asynchronously**.  Meaning, the browser fires off the request and while that's happening, code after that line executes without pause.

jQuery provides a callback function parameter to get script that allows you to do something after the asynchronous fetch is finished.

Try this:

```
 var script = function(){
      var scripts = {};
      return {
           load: function(jsurl, callback){
                $.getScript(jsurl, callback);
           },
           run: function(js){
                window[js].apply(this,null);
           }
     }
 };
```

Then, when using it:

```
 ctlr.load( 'remote.js', function(){
      // remote script successfully loaded
      ctlr.run( 'remotefunc' ); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's telling you window['remotefunc'] is undefined is because you are not giving it time to actually download and execute the remote script before attempting to call a function defined in it.

The remote script is loaded asynchronously, which means the script execution isn't paused while waiting for a response.

You will need to either re-implement the getScript method to be synchronous or somehow work your class around the fact that the function will not be available in any determinate amount of time.

EDIT: Just found another possible solution, try calling this before your request

```
$.ajaxSetup({async: false});
```

This will make the getScript method synchronous

Comment: I wouldn't do make the method synchronous.  The entire point of doing it asynchronously is so that execution is not blocking on network delay.

Comment: @Kane: Thanks! Put your code before $.getScript, problem remains though

Answer (score 0):

Could this be a timing issue?

In your working example you call the function in a callback which `jQuery` will not invoke until the script is loaded. In your non-working example, you call the function immediately after `getScript` which is asynchronously loading the script.